# Is the visit ratio vector non-negative in each of its components?

Tags: queueing

I am reading the [wiki on mean value analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_analysis). I am writing a Python implementation of it, and it occurred to me that I was getting some negative values. I want to validate whether that is expected behaviour. It describes the following mathematical setup:

> Consider a closed queueing network of $K$ M/M/1 queues, with M customers circulating in the system. Suppose that the customers are indistinguishable from each other, so that the network has a single class of customers. To compute the mean queue length and waiting time at each of the nodes and throughput of the system we use an iterative algorithm starting with a network with 0 customers.
>
> Write $\mu_i$ for the service rate at node $i$ and $P$ for the customer routing matrix where element $p_{ij}$ denotes the probability that a customer finishing service at node i moves to node j for service. To use the algorithm, we first compute the **visit ratio row vector** $v$, a vector such that $\mathbf{v} = \mathbf{v} P$.
>
> Now write $L_i(n)$ for the mean number of customers at queue i when there is a total of $n$ customers in the system (this includes the job currently being served at queue i) and $W_j(n)$ for the mean time spent by a customer in queue i when there is a total of n customers in the system. Denote the throughput of a system with $m$ customers by $\lambda_m$.

I am solving for the components of $\mathbf{v}$ using [Cramer's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule):

$$v_i = \frac{\det \left(P^T_i \right)}{\det \left( P^T \right)}$$

where the transpose is motivated by

$$\mathbf{v} P = \mathbf{v} \iff  P^T \mathbf{v}^T = \mathbf{v}^T.$$

Does $\mathbf{v}$ have to satisfy $\mathbf{v} \geq \mathbf{0}$ component-wise?

Comment: Just a comment: in dimensions greater than $2$ or so, you *really* don't want to use Cramer's Rule.  It has terrible numerical behavior and terrible use of computational resources.  There are extremely efficient stable methods to find $v$ because it's an eigenvector with maximal absolute eigenvalue.

Comment: Isn't $P$ just a Markov transition matrix?

Comment: @whuber Yes, $P$ is a [stochastic matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_matrix) with fixed values.

Comment: Then it's easy to show all eigenvalues of $P$ have moduli less than $1$ (for otherwise the limiting probabilities diverge) and that $1$ is an eigenvalue (from the sum-to-unity condition).  Evidently $v$ is a (left) eigenvector with eigenvalue $1.$ A standard way to find the largest absolute eigenvalue is to iteratively apply $P.$ This requires the eigenspace is one-dimensional, so a general-purpose solution has to deal with that possibility--but the method is efficient. A simple theorem is such a $v$ exists with non-negative components.

Comment: I can't see how your formula is a solution, though...

Comment: @whuber In hindsight, my formula may simply be an error. I should really do a refresh on my linear algebra!